# UIButtons in specific zone of the screen make delay on Touch Down event

Tags: ios, uibutton, delay, custom-keyboard

I'm creating a Custom Keyboard for iOS. I have 4 rows of keys, each key have two actions: Touch Down to highlight button, and Touch Up Inside to unhighlight the button in 0.4 seconds. 
But at the left edge of the screen there is a zone where Touch Down event of any button makes a delay for about quarter of second to show highlight.
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B33Yo.jpg) 
So to see highlighted version, I had to hold the button, or swipe right from it. The buttons are the same, no difference at all. When I switch from letters to symbols, this left edge zone also makes the same delay. I've tried to move all the keys to the right, about 20px, and they worked fine, without delay. Ok, stick to the edge back, and delay came back also. Then I noticed, that pressing the button on its right edge, about 1-2 pixels made no delay at all. So, it seems like the problem is in this left side edge zone of the screen particularly.
By the way, I am running this app on my 5S, I've tried to run it on my friend's 5C, the same problem. But when I run it in the simulator, there is no such delay.

Comment: This question is similar to the one posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196205/animation-delay-on-left-side-of-screen-in-ios-keyboard-extension/39564772#39564772. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use new iOS 11 feature to solve this problem definitely.

```
var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge { get }
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `UIInputViewController` on iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

I'm too creating a custom keyboard, and as far as I understand, that happens due to `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` not working properly when overridden inside `UIInputViewController`, at least on iOS 13.

When you override this property in a regular view controller, it works as expected:

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return [.left, .bottom, .right]
}
```

That's however not the case for `UIInputViewController`.

**UPD:** It appears, gesture recognizers will still get `.began` state update, without the delay. So, instead of following the rather messy solution below, you can add a custom gesture recognizer to handle touch events.

You can quickly test this adding `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with `minimumPressDuration = 0` to your control view.

**Another solution:**

My original workaround was calling `touch down` effects inside `hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?`, which is called even when the touches are delayed for the view.

You have to ignore the "real" touch down event, when it fires about 0.4s later or simultaneously with `touch up inside` event. Also, it's probably better to apply this hack only in case the tested point is inside ~20pt lateral margins.

So for example, for a view with equal to screen width, the implementation may look like:

```
let edgeProtectedZoneWidth: CGFloat = 20

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let result = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

    guard result == self else {
        return result
    }

    if point.x < edgeProtectedZoneWidth || point.x > bounds.width-edgeProtectedZoneWidth
    {
        if !alreadyTriggeredFocus {
            isHighlighted = true
        }
        triggerFocus()
    }

    return result
}

private var alreadyTriggeredFocus: Bool = false

@objc override func triggerFocus() {
    guard !alreadyTriggeredFocus else { return }
    super.triggerFocus()
    alreadyTriggeredFocus = true
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)

    alreadyTriggeredFocus = false
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    alreadyTriggeredFocus = false
}
```

...where `triggerFocus()` is the method you call on `touch down` event. Alternatively, you may override `touchesBegan(_:with:)`.